# Installing CouchDB on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: couchdb

I have been trying to install couchdb in my newly upgraded ubuntu 17.10 but to no avail. I have used many resources including 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-couchdb-and-futon-on-ubuntu-14-04
but coudn't get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I later discovered that nothing was wrong with the installation but with my new upgrade(ubuntu 17.10)

The previous PPA does not work with ubuntu 17.10, and an engineer from couchdb has created a new PPA for ubuntu 17.10 users https://launchpad.net/~jderose/+archive/ubuntu/couchdb-1.7.0

So all you need do is just point your ppa to https://launchpad.net/~jderose/+archive/ubuntu/couchdb-1.7.0 when installing couchdb following this
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-couchdb-and-futon-on-ubuntu-14-04 and everything should be fine

Follow this post to install it seamlessly

https://medium.com/@tomiwatech_45998/installing-couchdb-on-ubuntu-17-10-18148e2eb846

I hope this helps someone. Thanks